# How can I compute these values in groups?

Tags: group-theory, discrete-mathematics

In the group of $\mathbb{Z}_{17}^* $, $ \overline{13}^{-1}=?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search, and ye shall find.

Alternately, use the Extended Euclidean Algorithm.

Alternately, take powers of $13$ modulo $17$ until you find a $k$ such that $13^k\equiv 1\pmod{17}$. Then (the congruence class of) $13^{k-1}$ is your answer.

Alternately, we want $13x\equiv 1\pmod{17}$, that is, $-4x\equiv -16\pmod{17}$, that is, $x\equiv 4\pmod{17}$.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Euclidean algorithm. Note that 
$$\begin{align}17&=13(1)+4\\
13&=4(3)+1.
\end{align}$$
Backtracking through the equations and expressing $1$ as a linear combination of $13$ and $17$ we find that $1=13(4)-17(3).$ Reducing modulo $17$ implies that $4=13^{-1}$.